# CakePHP Validation - isUnique OR inList

Tags: validation, cakephp

*(New to CakePHP, so this may be an obvious thing, but I was unable to find a solution after searching for a couple of hours - the ambiguous nature of "or", I guess...)*

I am trying to modify an existing CakePHP validation rule, which uses the `isUnique` rule, so that it will validate for values which satisfy either the `isUnique` rule or an `inList` rule.

The previous code:

```
'isUnique' => array(
  'rule' => 'isUnique' ,
  'message' => "We're sorry, but this QA number is already being used.",
  'last' => TRUE,
),
```

My (faulty) code:

```
'isUnique' => array(
  'rule' => array( 
    'isUnique' ,
    array( 'inList' , array( '111213' , '141516' , '171819' , '202122' ) )
  ) ,
  'message' => "We're sorry, but this number is already being used.",
  'last' => TRUE,
),
```

So, (as simple as this may be), how can you string CakePHP validation rules together with an "OR" logical operator? I can see that you can apply a cascade of "AND" rules (with each testing for a specific issue and, if failing that test, rejecting the value), but "OR" rules have me scratching my head...

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make that a [custom validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1181/Adding-your-own-Validation-Methods). Add this in your model:

```
public function isUniqueOrInList(array $data, array $list) {
    return in_array(current($data), $list) || $this->isUnique($data);
}
```

Then declare your rule like:

```
'rule' => array('isUniqueOrInList', array('111213', '141516', '171819', '202122'))
```

Comment: You're a saint! Thanks for your help - my first foray into CakePHP, so I was clueless.

Comment: for performance reasons I would switch the two conditions. the latter does not need a DB call

Comment: You may try to use 'allowEmpty' as in date validation : 

    'dateField' => array('rule' => array('date','dmy'),
       'message' => 'Enter valid date.',
       'allowEmpty' => true)